# Замена старого файла в local storage на новый

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, svg-спрайт

Очень долго искал способ вставить `SVG-спрайт` из отдельного файла в `HTML` код, чтобы при этом он оставался чистым, а спрайты вызывались по ID из этого спрайта.

Нашёл боле менее рабочий способ, но он добавляет этот спрайт в память браузера (из-за чего он работает только на серверах), а уже потом использует его.

```
(function(window, document) {
    'use strict';
    var file = 'img/svg_sprite.svg',
        revision = 1;
    if (!document.createElementNS || !document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg').createSVGRect) return true;
    var isLocalStorage = 'localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null,
        request,
        data,
    insertIT = function() {
        document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', data);
    },
    insert = function() {
      if (document.body) insertIT();
      else document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', insertIT);
    };
    if (isLocalStorage && localStorage.getItem('inlineSVGrev') == revision) {
        data = localStorage.getItem('inlineSVGdata');
        if (data) {
            insert();
            return true;
        }
    }
    try {
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', file, true);
        request.onload = function() {
            if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
                data = request.responseText;
                insert();
                if (isLocalStorage) {
                    localStorage.setItem('inlineSVGdata', data);
                    localStorage.setItem('inlineSVGrev', revision);
                }
            }
        }
        request.send();
    } catch (e) {}
}(window, document));
```

В данный момент я не на столько продвинут, чтобы читать такой код, но проблема вот в чём: после того, как я меняю свой спрайт, он не перезаписывается в памяти браузера, а очистка кэша тоже не помогает, приходится вручную удалять его из памяти, что очень неудобно.

**Можно ли сюда куда-нибудь как-нибудь вписать код проверки хотя бы размера файла (лучше, конечно, хеш-суммы), при котором он бы заменял старый файл?**

Comment: Что бы проверить, изменился ли файл, надо его сначала загрузить с сервера. Ну или положиться на кэширование браузера. Если не хотите, что бы файл брался из localStorage, уберите строку `return true;` - это самый простой и глупый способ)

Comment: Тогда "добрую" половину кода можно удалить?

Comment: Зачем вы придумываете велосипед с локалстораджем, если для этих целей специально придумали сервис воркер?

Answer (score 2):

Может попробовать использовать проверенный и надёжный способ добавления SVG-спрайта из отдельного файла в HTML с помощью `<object>`.
 Тем более здесь есть целый раздел ответов и вопросов, как это сделать. Тег [svg-спрайт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svg-%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82)

### Подключение файла спрайта

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="sprite.svg" >
  Your browser does not support SVG
</object>
```

### Вызов разных иконок из файла спрайта в разных местах HTML

```
<div class="container">
<svg class="icon-box" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
      <use xlink:href="images/sprite.svg#user"></use>
</svg>   
</div> 

<div class="container">
<svg class="icon-box" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
      <use xlink:href="images/sprite.svg#home"></use>
</svg>   
</div>
```

где `#user`, `#home` уникальные идентификаторы иконок внутри svg спрайта

Тег `<object>` добавления файла спрайта в HTML необходимо разместить в листинге выше вызовов иконок, лучше в хедере. Это понятно, иконки должны загрузиться до вызова их в конкретном месте странички.

### Подключение внешней таблицы стилей

В шапке файла спрайта необходимо добавить путь до внешней таблицы стилей:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="Svgstyle.css"?>   
<svg   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">  
Код спрайта 
</svg>
```

### Структура файла `sprite.svg`

```html
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="Svgstyle.css"?>   
<svg   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 24 24">  
<symbol id="user" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
<path код иконки ..... />
</symbol>
 <symbol id="home" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
 <path код иконки ..... />
 </symbol>  
 
   <symbol id="settings" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
 <path код иконки ..... />
 </symbol>

</svg>
```

Comment: <use xlink:href="images/sprite.svg#user"></use>
  Ссылка ведь ведёт на внешний файл. т.е. сам спрайт не вставлен в HTML-разметку, я правильно понимаю? Именно поэтому я на данном способе не остановился. А код, что я нашёл - вставляет его, а вставка самой иконки выглядит так:
     <use xlink:href="#user"></use>


Т.е., спрайт вставлен в разметку и я не указываю путь к файлу

Comment: @Сергей можно так заканчивать команду `/>` можно и так `</use>` зависит  от контекста :) Обязательно  `</use>` если внутри контейнера `<use> .... <animate> ..... </animate> </use>` находится другая команда

Comment: @Сергей спрайт через <object> добавляется в html разметку, можете через инспектор посмотреть, что он попадает в дом. И что ценно в этом методе - идет только один запрос к серверу, а дальше иконки уже вызываются из спрайта по `id`