# Подключить svg (xml) к странице html + возможность управлять ID самого рисунка

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, svg-спрайт

Имеется рисунок `svg`, я его сохранил в `xml`  папке с сайтом и нужно как-то вывести этот рисунок на страницу + управлять отдельными объектами этого `svg` рисунка с помощью его `ID`. Может кто сталкивался с этим?

Comment: как обычно...  Ничего сложного... Все тоже самое, что и с `DOMобычным элементом`

Comment: Хорошо ,а как тогда по Click менять цвет ID самого  svg обьекта ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так как правила сайта не рекомендуют в ответе только ссылки на ответы-решения, приведу лишь часть ответа, которая уже поможет решить ваш вопрос, и затем дам ссылку на более полный ответ, как сделать спрайт, как управлять стилями элементов спрайта.

---

Может попробовать использовать проверенный и надёжный способ добавления SVG-спрайта из отдельного файла в HTML с помощью .

1. Подключение файла спрайта

`<object type="image/svg+xml" data="sprite.svg" >
  Your browser does not support SVG
</object>`

2. Вызов разных иконок из файла спрайта в разных местах HTML

```html
<div class="container">
<svg class="icon-box" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
      <use xlink:href="images/sprite.svg#user"></use>
</svg>   
</div> 

<div class="container">
<svg class="icon-box" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
      <use xlink:href="images/sprite.svg#home"></use>
</svg>   
</div>
```

Более развернутый ответ [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/784436/28748)

Comment: Саша я ему вчера писал о `use`

Answer (score 4):

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  loadSvgInto(document.body, 'https://httpbin.org/image/svg').then(svg => {
    svg.setAttribute('height', '170px'); 
    const rndColor = () => '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 0x111 + 0xddd).toString(16), 
          letters  = svg.querySelectorAll('#svg-text #S, #svg-text #V, #svg-text #G');
    for (let letter of letters)
      letter.style.transition = 'fill 1.5s linear'; 
    setInterval(() => {
      for (let letter of letters)
        letter.setAttribute('fill', rndColor()); 
    }, 1500); 
  }); 
});

// Добавляет SVG-разметку из url в элемент el, возвращает промис со ссылкой на добавленное (на корневой узел). 
// В отличие от более простого метода добавления через <object>, позволяет избежать ограничений политики same-origin при доступе к дочерним узлам
function loadSvgInto(el, url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    xhr.open('GET', url); 
    xhr.overrideMimeType('image/svg+xml');
    xhr.onloadend = function () {
      if (this.status === 200) {
        let de = this.responseXML.documentElement;
        el.appendChild(de);
        resolve(de);
      }
      else
        reject(); 
    }; 
    xhr.send();
  }); 
}
```

Если нужно навесить id, то просто

```
loadSvgInto(...).then(svg => { 
  svg.id = 'any-id'; 
  ... 
});
```

Comment: отличный ответ, но на мой взгляд для людей, которые начинают разбираться с svg в первую очередь необходимо разобраться в нативном svg, как это всё работает, а затем переходить на новый уровень - использовать JS

Comment: Спасибо ОГРОМНОЕ за помощь , сейчас буду дальше разбираться .

Comment: Просто сейчас ищу самый простой вариант например той же замены цвета СВГ-ешного рисунка по нажатию кнопки .Чтоб большой код не писать

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, относительно порядка изучения, я с Вами полностью согласен. Но все-таки, раз автор хочет манипулировать SVG-элементами средствами JS, мы никак не можем заставлять его отказаться от этой идеи. Тем более что в сумме с вашим ответом, получается почти полная картина возможных вариантов... не хватает разве что манипуляций свойствами посредством CSS-правил :)

Comment: @technoimpextechnoimpex, рад был помочь! Если в примере что-то непонятно - спрашивайте, я дополню.

Comment: Можешь глянуть эту тему "Управление SVG по его id
" Код вроде как правильно написал но по нажатию на "Насос-1"или 2 цвет самого насоса с красного не меняется почему-то...